# How can i create list and add elements in python?

Tags: python-3.x, list, collections, insert, append

I am adding below readable code for creating a 'list' and all methods of add element. Here is the code:

## Create list. Add element using append(),insert()

```
# Create lists
list1 = [1,4,6,8] # integer list.
list2 = [] # Empty List.
list3 = [1.2,'Raj',1] # mixed list.

# Print Created lists
print(list1)
print(list2)
print(list3)

# Add element using append(). Elements will be added at the last of list.
list1.append(11)
list1.append(12)
print(list1)

# Add elements in an empty list using for loop and append()
list2 = []
string = 'abcdef'
for ele in string:
list2.append(ele)
print(list2)

# Add element using insert(). Element will add at any position using index
list4 = ['r','j','s','h']
list4.insert(1,'a')
list4.insert(3,'e')
print(list4)
```

Comment: What is the problem

Comment: The code will execute without any issue. There is no problem.

Answer (score 0):

[i have shared the link of image where both input and output is shown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c97Xi.png)